# How do I make a class inherit only some of its parent's initialize method?

Tags: ruby, class

I have a class which begins like this:

```
class Hedgehogs
  attr_accessor :name, :age, :color, :weight, :fur_quality, :disposition, :sexual_aggression, :has_syphilis # ... etc etc.
```

with a long list of attributes, defined by method `initialize`, which vary widely for each new instance of the class.

But I've found that Madagascar hedgehogs are always brown, sexually aggressive, and immune to syphilis, so these attributes would always be the same.

Should I make a new class `MadagascarHedgehogs` for efficiency's sake, and if so, how do I establish that the new class inherits `Hedgehogs`' properties, only with select attributes from `initialize` determined in the class definition instead?

Comment: inherit and override whatever properties that differ from the super class

Comment: But then I would still have to initialize the to-be-overridden properties at bogus values. I thought there might be a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Can you post your `initialize` method?

Comment: It is long, but all it has is the standard list of `arg = @arg`, and a few empty hashes to be populated later.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways you could approach this. I would probably add a hook method that you call from `initialize` and override on your subclasses. I would also recommend using a hash instead of individual arguments for `initialize`, especially since you have so many variables:

```
class Hedgehog
  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |key, value|
      instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
    end
    set_constant_attributes
  end

  def set_constant_attributes
  end
end

class MadagascarHedgehog
  def set_constant_attributes
    @default1 = 'default value 1'
  end
end
```

You could also do this without the hook method by overriding `initialize`:

```
class MadagascarHedgehog
  def initialize(attributes = {})
    super(attributes)
    @default1 = 'default value 1'
  end
end
```

However, I find this less expressive in general, and depending on who is going to be reading/maintaining this code in the future, I think it would be easier to say 'define constant attributes in the `set_constant_attributes` method', rather than trusting them to properly override init.

A third way would be to just override the reader methods, which is simple and terse (and now that I think about it, probably my favorite):

```
class MadagascarHedgehog
  def color
    'brown'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was incredibly helpful! I didn't even know there was a built-in method `instance_variable_set`. I definitely should be using that. I love the last method you listed; I never would have thought to undermine the `attr_accessor`'s "behind the scenes" activity directly (that is what's happening, right?).

Comment: Yes, basically `attr_accessor` defines two methods per argument (a getter and a setter) that wrap your instance variables in a method call. It's generally good practice to use these instead of referring to your instance variables directly (except in `initialize`), and this situation is one reason why - it makes the return values easy to change by simply rewriting the method, and as long as the rest of your class uses the getter, that's as far as you need to go.

Comment: Awesome. I love Ruby; it's like they thought of everything.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a method that builds madagascar hedgehogs.

```
class Hedgehogs
  attr_accessor :name, :age, :color, :weight, :fur_quality, :disposition, :sexual_aggression, :has_syphilis

  def initialize(opts)
    @name = opts[:name] || 'Default Name'
    @age = opts[:age] || 'Default Age'
    ... etc ..
  end

  def self.madagascar_hedgehog
    self.new(:name => 'Madagascar', :age => 50)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think your classes should be in the singular, i.e. `Hedgehog` and `MadagascarHedgehog`.

You don't show your `initialize` method, so I imagine you're passing it a hash since you have so many attributes to initialize.

Suppose your main class looks like this

```
class Hedgehog

  attr_accessor :name, :age, :color, :weight, :fur_quality, :disposition, :sexual_aggression, :has_syphilis

end
```

then you can write an `initialize` method in your subclass that defaults the constant attributes and passes the values to the superclass for the actual initialization.

You can also disable the attribute write accessors so that those values don't get overwritten, if you wish, using `undef_method`.

```
class MadagascarHedgehog < Hedgehog

  def initialize(args)

    args[:color] = 'brown'
    args[:sexual_aggression] = 'aggressive'
    args[:has_syphilis] = 'immune'

    super(args)

  end

  undef_method :color=
  undef_method :sexual_aggression=
  undef_method :has_syphilis=

end
```